# How to display transparent view to show the Upload successful message on current view and then go back to root view controller

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiview

In my current view controller i m uploading the content to server and i want to show the user that the upload was successful and then take him to the root view controller to perform another action.
Is there a way i can do it.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [MBProgressHUD](https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD)

Comment: +1 @jin. MBProgressHUD is the way to show progress and "toasts" in iOS. Keep in mind that keeping users unnecessarily stuck on a view so they can read a message may not be the best user experience - Too short of a delay and it looks like "reading test", too long and it annoys. You may be better off switching to root (popToRootViewControllerAnimated:(BOOL)animated;) and showing a "toast" MBP HUD about success. In case of failure stay on upload controller and throw an alert.